# How to show a video when the app loads first time?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

How can I make an app play a video walkthrough (only) the first time it is loaded and then close itself and not play the next time user uses the app?
I found some instructions on showing a pop-up message but this didn't help really :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On launch read a setting from `NSUserDefaults`. If not present play the video. When the video finishes write that same setting to `NSUserDefaults`. In the next launch the setting will be found and you can skip the video part.

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstLaunch"];) {
    // play the video
    // when done:
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstLaunch"]
}
```

Not sure if you're asking how to play the video too. If that's the case, you may want to split the question in two and be more specific.